# Seeking Septic Tank Location Data for Southeastern United States?

Tags: data, census, united-states

I am compiling a database of septic tank locations to make some rough estimates of the magnitude of return flow to the groundwater system for the Floridan aquifer system. Ideally I would have a lat/long for each tank so that I can identify, at the census block level, the average number of persons per household to compute the number of gallons of flow-through per day. A dataset of this detail has been developed for the state of Florida and possibly for Georgia as well. Records for South Carolina and especially Alabama are not as robust and I would need to resort to some county-wide tally. I have only managed to find state-wide counts on [uscensus.gov](http://www.census.gov/housing/census/data/sewage.html) through 1990. Block-group level data seem to be available through American Fact Finder 2 from the 2010 census, but only for American territories such as Guam or the Virgin Islands (Topics -> Housing -> Physical Characteristics -> Sewage Disposal).

Can anyone point me toward any datasets which are at least at the county level?

Depending on the quality I may elect to use such a dataset for the entire estimation process to maintain continuity between states.

Answer (score 1):

You can find septic tank locations in FL at [FGDL](https://www.fgdl.org/metadataexplorer/explorer.jsp). It will be managed a little bit differently state-to-state but you can search further.

An example from GA would be [Gwinnett County](https://www.gwinnettcounty.com/portal/gwinnett/Departments/InformationTechnologyServices/GeographicInformationSystems/GISDataandMapSales?portal:windowState=normal&portal:componentId=gtnd5e38f46-ace5-4ffd-bcd6-73917690a9b4&interactionstate=JBPNS_rO0ABXd4ABNzdHJ1dHMucG9ydGxldC5tb2RlAAAAAQAEdmlldwAVc3RydXRzLnBvcnRsZXQuYWN0aW9uAAAAAQAZL3ZpZXcvaW5kZXhQcm9kdWN0RGV0YWlscwAJcHJvZHVjdElkAAAAAQAJR0lTX1NFVC01AAdfX0VPRl9f&portal:type=action&portal:portletMode=view) septic locations (oddly enough the layer is listed under the stormwater group). The downside is Gwinnett Co charges $100 for the data.